# Converting Dropdown list to int

Tags: c#

hello mates i am trying to store value from dropdown list to an integer but i am getting an exception **Input string was not in a correct format.**

```
int experienceYears = Convert.ToInt32("DropDownList1.SelectedValue");
```

please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the quotes; the code as it stands is trying to convert the literal string `"DropDownList1.SelectedValue"` to an integer, which it can't.

```
int experienceYears = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it without the quotes:

```
int experienceYears = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
```